# How to redirect page after successful Firebase log in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to redirect the user to a new page upon successful log in and/or registration using Firebase authentication.

I have tried following the documentation code provided by Firebase, but it results in an endless loop of being redirected to the same page.

I think the issue may be with how I am calling the initApp() function.

```
/**
     * Handles the sign in button press.
     */
function handleLogIn() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        // [START signout]
        firebase.auth().signOut();
        console.log("We have signed out :(");
        window.location = 'login.html';
        // [END signout]
    } else {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        if (email.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter an email address.');
            return;
        }
        if (password.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter a password.');
            return;
        }
        // Sign in with email and pass.
        // [START authwithemail]
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                alert('Wrong password.');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        });
        // [END authwithemail]
    }
    //successful log in
    initApp();
}

/**
 * Handles the sign up button press.     
 **/
function handleSignUp() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (email.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter an email address.');
        return;
    }
    if (password.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter a password.');
        return;
    }
    // Sign in with email and pass.
    // [START createwithemail]
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
            alert('The password is too weak.');
        } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    });
    // [END createwithemail]
}


/**
     * initApp handles setting up UI event listeners and registering Firebase auth listeners:
     *  - firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged: This listener is called when the user is signed in or
     *    out, and that is where we update the UI.
     */
function initApp() {
    // Listening for auth state changes.
    // [START authstatelistener]
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        //document.getElementById('quickstart-verify-email').disabled = true;
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            window.location = 'index.html';
            var displayName = user.displayName;
            var email = user.email;
            console.log("Houston we are logged in! " + email);
            var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
            var photoURL = user.photoURL;
            var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
            var uid = user.uid;
            var providerData = user.providerData;
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            if (!emailVerified) {
            }
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        } else {
            // User is signed out.
            window.location = 'login.html';
            // [START_EXCLUDE]

            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    });
    // [END authstatelistener]

}
//check state change
window.onload = function () {
    initApp();
};
```

Comment: Are you using AngularFire? I suggest you can just simply set the window location using JavaScript in your success callback instead of using Angularfire. Someone told that don't mix jQuery with Angular if possible, or you will run into errors.

Comment: I am not using any frameworks here.